# Classical 3-body problem in 1D

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, three-body-problem

Consider three masses on a line (1D) with repulsive forces going with the inverse square law.  Is there any known closed form solution to the equations of motion?

For a symmetric initial condition, the solution is rather trivial, however with asymmetric initial conditions, the central mass will oscillate between the two with some damping.

Comment: Do the bodies pass through one another or something? Not understanding what exactly would happen if 3 mass constrained to 1 dimension would behave.

Comment: I updated the question to answer this. No collisions, just oscillations, I'd be interested in the both like and opposite charge solutions.

Comment: Unless they repel each other, how can they avoid colliding if they move on a single line?

Comment: I think @StarStrides means, they just pass through each other. Though at that point the forces would diverge so not sure if that would allow good solutions.

Comment: So then what happens when two bodies are at the same position (or really close)?

Comment: So your question is whether the system of equations $ \ddot x_i = \sum_{j\neq i} G m_j /(x_j-x_i)^2$, for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ and with the appropriate signs, has closed-form solutions (on intervals where solutions exist)?

Comment: They would pass through each other, yes.  There is a singularity only at the crossings, which should be at a single point.  - Yes, mathematically, this is correct @anderstood thanks.

Comment: Ok but what happens at these singularities..?

Comment: Consider first the case they are repelling charges, no singularities will occur

Comment: @StarStrides Maybe you should ask math.SE instead, by formulating your question as whether the following system of 3 ODEs has known closed-form solutions on some intervals [...]

Comment: In my opinion I think 3 body should remain a physics problem and perhaps math problems which can be abstracted, can be handled separately. Then the two can compete.

Comment: And maybe for cases with singular points its pointless to ask because they simply aren't defined, and there is no natural definition either, no experimental data etc. to suggest one way or other what happens. The key issue if the particles' speed is reduced to zero or perhaps infinitely accelerated at that moment or something else? Maybe something increases or decreases such that there would or wouldn't be continuity for some behavior at the singular point. And the case that they are repulsive seems more or less trivial, they would simply seek to maximize distance between one another.